# C++11 template error message: "cannot call member function without object"

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The following is code for generating an expression template for adding N vectors, but currently I'm only looking at adding two vectors.

```
template < typename Operation, typename Va>
struct VectorExpression < Operation, Va >
{
    friend Va;
    typedef VectorExpression< Operation, Va> This;
    const Operation& op;
    const Va& vector;

    inline VectorExpression ( Operation oper, const Va& first) : op(oper), vector(first) {};

    inline auto size() const ->decltype( vector.size() ) {
        return vector.size();
    };

    inline auto operator[]( size_t i ) const 
        ->decltype( vector[i] ) {
        return vector[i];
        };
};

template < typename Operation, typename Va, typename ... Vs >
struct VectorExpression <Operation, Va, Vs...> : protected VectorExpression< Operation, Vs...>
{
    friend Va;
    typedef VectorExpression< Operation, Va, Vs...> This;
    typedef VectorExpression< Operation, Vs... > Base;
    const Operation op;
    const Va& vector;

    inline VectorExpression ( Operation oper, const Va& first, const Vs&... vs ) : VectorExpression< Operation, Vs...>(oper, vs...), op(oper), vector(first) {};

    inline auto size() const ->decltype( vector.size() ) {
        return vector.size();
    };

    inline auto operator[]( size_t i ) const //This line is where the error says it is happening
        ->decltype( op( vector[i], Base::operator[](i) ) ) {
        return op( vector[i], Base::operator[](i) );
        };
};
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt to compile the preceding, I get the following error message:

```
error: cannot call member function 'decltype (((const VectorExpression<Operation, Va>*)this)->VectorExpression<Operation, Va>::vector[i]) 
    VectorExpression<Operation, Va>::operator[](size_t) const 
    [with 
        Operation = adder<std::complex<double>, double>; 
        Va = Vector<double, false>; 
        decltype (((const VectorExpression<Operation, Va>*)this)->VectorExpression<Operation, Va>::vector[i]) = const double&; size_t = long unsigned int]'  without object
```

I'm not sure where the problem lies.  It seems to be a fairly simple recursive definition of `operator[]`, adding the vector in the current object with all the base class vectors.

Any ideas?  I don't believe that the rest of the code is relevant[ Edit: but the header can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/JNYFihBb), and the test "main" can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/38X9zC8p), but if you would like to see it, let me know.  Also, is there any way in C++11 to print out types in locations for debugging this kind of problem?

Comment: It would be good if you could provide some complete code that we could try to compile on our environment (including the way you instantiate these templates, if you do). This is partial, and it may be harder to spot the error without playing with the code

Comment: @AndyProwl:  Done, I added links to a header file and instantiation file.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Good catch! I wouldn't have spotted that one

Comment: @SethCarnegie:  Wow, I thought I had tried that, but apparently not... Thanks!  If you write it in an answer, I'll give you credit for that.

Comment: Unlike `g++-4.7`, `clang-3.0` does a very good job at telling you where this is going wrong, it explicitly marks the `Base::operator[](i)` inside the `decltype` section.

Comment: Unlike g++-4.7, g++-4.8 does a very good job at telling you where this is going wrong, it explicitly marks the `Base::operator[](i)` inside the `decltype` section. ;-)  And Clang 3.3 (trunk 174683) segfaults

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Clang 3.2 also segfaults.  I'll have to grab gcc 4.8.

Comment: @AndrewSpott, 4.8.0 is not actually released yet, but should be within a few weeks, and even then I never recommend using a 4.x.0 release for anything critical without doing a lot of testing. 4.8.0 will be great for trying out C++11 features and getting better diagnostics though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do `Base::operator[](i)` in the `decltype` since it's not in the body of a member function; you have to do `this->Base::operator[](i)`.

Comment: This is familiar, and for posterity I'm trying to find the rule for this buried within the lookup rules. Do you know where it is?